# How can I Take value of input field and put in Form Builder?

Tags: angular

I have input field which value must be 2, but in that field must be written "Prosummer" and then I need to put value of 2 in Form Builder.I am using Angular 15.This is my code:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" formControlName="rolaId" type="text" value="2" placeholder="Prosumer">
```

.ts

```
  this.signUpForm = this.forma.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  rolaId:['', Validators.required],
})
```

When I run this code placeholder is Prosumer but in Form Builder value of rolaId is not 2.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `ReactiveFormsModule`, you have control over your form in your code, not the in the template HTML, so setting the value of 2 with `[value]="2"` is not going to work.

If you want to set up that hard-coded value initially, you could do it when the form is created, providing an initial value

```js
rolId = 2;

createForm(): void {
  this.signUpForm = this.forma.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    rolaId:[this.rolId, Validators.required],
  })
}
```

Or maybe you are getting that value from somewhere else, sometime later, you could then `patch` the particular form property `rolaId` using `patchValue`:

```js
updateRolId(id: number): void {
  this.form.get('rolaId')?.patchValue(id);
}
```

For more information about reactive forms, I suggest reading the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Yeah, but when I do this rolaId:[this.rolId, Validators.required] in my input field is wrtitten 2 and I need "Prosumer" in that field